# Orchestrating different bounded contexts, whose responsibility is it?

Tags: domain-driven-design, integration, soa, bounded-contexts

I have 3 separated services using different databases with REST interfaces:

- First service: Information about Customers
- Second service: Information about Customer Trades
- Third service: Information about Customer Documentation

Problem:
Every customer has a Status that should be evaluated based on his **trades** and **documents**.

Which service should be responsible for this evaluation and how should I implement the orchestration between the other services?

Comment: If you can, I'd create a 4th service.  This way you have a service that returns what you need, avoiding the problem (and over chattiness) of calling 2 services and merging the result set.  Otherwise, if you don't have access to be able to create a 4th service, maybe write a proxy service that through one call, calls the other 2 services and uses data caching to cache data where possible, to try help cut down on multiple calls in the future for commonly queried customers.

Comment: Adrian, can you move your comment into an answer so we can have a discussion around your opinion? Tks!!

Comment: Does customer status information need to be persisted or is it meant to be generated on the fly?

Comment: The status is not persisted, its generated on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, I'd create a 4th service. This way you have a service that returns what you need, avoiding the problem (and over chattiness) of calling 2 services and merging the result set. Otherwise, if you don't have access to be able to create a 4th service, maybe write a proxy service that through one call, calls the other 2 services and uses data caching to cache data where possible, to try help cut down on multiple calls in the future for commonly queried customers.